# What are the Best Practises When Using AJAX in Plugin Development?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax

I am in the middle of creating a plugin and everything works fine with the AJAX calls but one question I can't seem to find the answer to is about best practise.

I route the AJAX calls through `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and have my php functions in the theme `functions.php` script.

However, I've just thought that this doesn't seem such a good idea because what do you do when the user activates your plugin, do you need to create a function to write your code to functions.php on activation?

Similarly, what if the user changes theme?

Therefore, I was just wondering if there are other ways to do it or what is the common approach for this type of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress AJAX best practices are following:

1. Use `wp_localize_script` to declare JavaScript global variables;
2. Use `admin-ajax.php` script to handle all AJAX requests;
3. Use nonces and check for permissions;
4. Use [jQuery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin to submit forms.

Read [5 tips for using AJAX in WordPress](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) article for more details.

> What do you do when the user activates your plugin, do you need to
>   create a function to write your code to functions.php on activation?
>   Similarly, what if the user changes theme?

You don't have to care about it. If you write your own plugin and it uses AJAX requests, then it has to be implemented only inside your plugin, don't write code into theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could place the functions in your plugin file rather than the theme functions.php, I always thought that they just had to be in the theme file because that's where `admin-ajax.php` 'looked' for the functions.

Comment: @martincarlin87 Yes, you can write your AJAX hook functions in your plugin file too.

Comment: Also hint for a digital book about the topic: http://wpajax.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) on the Codex about AJAX in Plugins.

> Since Ajax is already built into the core WordPress administration screens, adding more administration-side Ajax functionality to your plugin is fairly straightforward.

What you have to do is, instead of putting `add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');` in your `functions.php`, you will put them in your plugin file.

Comment: I see, I didn't know you could place the functions in your plugin file rather than the theme functions.php, I always thought that they just had to be in the theme file because that's where `admin-ajax.php` 'looked' for the functions.